# Extract Contents of iframe for an element using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, iframe, beautifulsoup

My goal: scrape the data from a table on a webpage

[image]

What it looks like when you first inspect the source:

[image]

What it looks like when you expand the body under id = "AppContainer":

[image]

My code, less the lines I have used to try to get the data:

```
#################################
#variables
target_url = ['https://redacted_url']
page = ''


#################################
#download the page
page = requests.get(target_url[0])
#check if the download of the page was successful; 200 = success 403 = forbidden
page.status_code


#################################
#parse the page you downloaded
my_soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
```

What I have tried:

1. Navigating to the network tab in the source to find the URL of the iframe; result: no url with the data
2. my_soup.find_all("iframe"); result: when assigned to a variable the variable value was None
3. my_soup.find("div",{"id": "AppContainer"}); result:

```
<div id="AppContainer">
<!-- App rendered here -->
</div>
```

4. Tried getting to page with table using selenium, but I have a similar situation in that href to the page I want to go to is in iframe:

[image]

Result: error message:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"#/classic/ML0A1ZN"}
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)
```

The code I am using:

```
#################################
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
import time

#################################
#variables
try:
    target_url = ['https://app-aba.redacted_appname.com/']
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
page = ''


#################################
# initiating the webdriver and logging into application. Parameter includes the path of the webdriver. 
try:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\name.name\\Desktop\\chrome_driver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")  
    driver.get(target_url[0])
    driver.find_element_by_id("loginUsername").send_keys("email@company.com")
    driver.find_element_by_id("loginPassword").send_keys("password")
    driver.find_element_by_id("loginButton").click()
    time.sleep(60)
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("#/classic/ML0A1ZN").click()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: if the iframe is loaded dynamically (which it looks like it might be) you'll probably need to find another way to reach the link. Please also provide a minimally reproducible example

Comment: @MZ I added some code but in this case I am starting off be using Selinium, is this enough context? Thanks!